# show date range with interval 1 month using php

Tags: php, date

I am trying show data of user with date range of this current year, 
e.g  user click on date range, date range look like

```
 jan-2018 - fab-2018  
 fab-2018 - mar-2018
 mar-2018 - apr-2018
```

so on...
how can i make loop to show date like that 
thanks

Comment: How about posting some code that you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   $mes_anterior  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+$i, date("d"),   date("Y"));
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php